# Issue when connecting a socket application over a port forwarded over adb

Tags: python, android, c++, sockets, adb

I was developing an application which has a server on the PC and client as an android device connected over adb (USB).
I have setup port forwarding by: `adb forward tcp:5100 tcp:5100`

Whenever I'm trying to run my python server over this it says :

```
server.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5100))
OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

Here is my server code:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server:
        #server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    
        server.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5100))
        server.listen()
        
        print("Waitng for client Sockets " + socket.gethostname())
        conn, address = server.accept()
        with conn:
            print("Connected to framework", address)
            while True:
                recvdStr = conn.recv(1024)
                if not recvdStr:
                    break
                print("Received: " + recvdStr.decode())
```

Client code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_example_testframeworktest_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv* env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";

    int client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(5100);
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    connect(client, (sockaddr*)&serverAddr, sizeof(sockaddr));
    send(client, "sending test string", strlen("sending test string"), 0);
    send(client, "", strlen(""), 0);
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

After enabling port forwarding, netstat-an shows my port in this state:

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:5100         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the python server code and the android client side to talk each other you should use `adb` reverse instead of forward.
This is the `adb` command that you should use

```
adb reverse tcp:5100 tcp:5100
```

Comment: I did this, at least now I'm able to set up the python server. However, I am unable to connect the devices over sockets. I've edited the question to add the client code.

Comment: nvm, it's working, needed to add some permission in the manifest. Thanks!

Comment: @Md.MohsinHussain
I met a same issue. please tell me how to add and which permission added?

Comment: @Dream811 It's been two years so it's a little bit hazy, but if I recall correctly, I had to add network access permissions in the android manifest file.

Comment: You can try pinging your ip address from the device first to verify if you're actually on the same network?

Answer (score 1):

1. Connect phone with usb cable to PC.
2. Issue command: adb usb
3. Issue command: adb tcpip 5100
4. Issue command: adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: what should I put in those xxx.xxx ?

Comment: your phone IP Address

and one more think 

your PC and Mobile is must be connect in same network

Comment: I haven't connected the phone to the PC over a wireless connection. It's just connected over USB

Comment: your phone and Pc is conncted in same network?